# Поиск элемента внутри структуры iframe

Tags: html, jquery, iframe

Появилась у меня задача вставить на сайт виджет, курса криптовалют, но не один из виджетво в сети не подходить по дизайну, решено было как то спарсить информацию, но это тоже по опрееленным причинам не получилось, тогда было принято решение вставить подходящий виджет на сайт, но блок скрыть за пределами видимости и по средством jquery вытащить нужные данные из виджета и вставить куда надо.

виджет взял от сюда https://ru.mconvert.net/exchange-rates-widget#step-2

вставил его вот так

```
<div id="bitcouninf">
<!--Биткоин--><iframe src="https://mconvert.net/get-exchange-rates-widget?base=btc&amount=1&lang=ru&curr=kzt&theme=blue&type=1&font=1&ssl=1" width="100%" height="124" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe><div style="font-size:12px;font-family:arial;text-align:right;"><a href="https://ru.mconvert.net/" style="text-decoration:none;color:#999;">Конвертер валют</a></div>
</div>
```

и далее пишу js такой

```
window.onload=function(){
 var iFrameDOM = $("#bitcouninf").children('iframe').contents().find('.label-default').html();
alert(iFrameDOM);
}
```

так как интересующая информация находится в элемента с классом label-default
то его я и ищу внутри ифрейма, и для отладки в начале решил вывести просто алертом, получилось ли что то получить. но к сожалению alert выдает значение undefined. Не пойму почему, в гугле все пишут что надо использовать contents() как это делаю я. Подскажите что я сделал не правильно??

Comment: А с чего вы решили что сможете достать данные из iframe? Вы не имеете доступа к данным в iframe

Comment: @Arsen а как можно ли получить доступ? если используется сторонний сайт??

Comment: Доступы можете получить только взломав сайт(шутка), надо написать парсер и парсить данные, вот и всё. Что у вас не получалось при парсинге?

Comment: @Arsen Парсить пробовал на php через библиотеку - все работало отлично но не хотело на сайтах с htpps и чесно говоря мне этот метод приглянулся больше так как показалось что возни меньше)) но видимо буду пилить скоро тут пост с вопросом про парсинг уже

Comment: а зачем вам библиотека? напишите сами и проблем с https не должно быть.Используйте DOMDocument::loadHTML, всё очень просто, прочитайте доки http://php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.loadhtml.php